# Which of these possible multi-choice answers is correct and why?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, word-order, subject-verb-inversion, indirect-question

A Chinese teacher of English asked me about the following, taken from an English test for Chinese people. It's quite tricky I think.

I would like to know three things:

1. Which answer or answers do you consider to be correct?
2. If you consider an answer to be wrong, why do you think it is wrong?
3. How would you reword these answers to make them acceptable?

Nanjing is a popular city with a long history. Could you tell me ______ .

A. where can visitors enjoy delicious Nanjing snacks?
B. when is the best time to visit the Confucious Temple?
C. how will people get to the Zhongshan Hill Scenic Area?
D. why was the city also called Jianye in ancient times?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please see the **Linked** duplicates to the right. Every one of those is wrong because they are inverting the subject and its verb the way you do with a direct question, which is always wrong in embedded or indirect questions where the subject comes first instead. The correct versions are A. Could you tell me where visitors can enjoy delicious Nanjing snacks?
B. Could you tell me when the best time to visit the Confucious Temple is? 
C. Could you tell me how people will get to the Zhongshan Hill Scenic Area?
D. Could you tell me why the city was also called Jianye in ancient times?